# Adding DateDiff column to PHP table using MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, datediff

I'm trying to add a column to my database table that shows the difference between the timestamp and the current date. I've tried creating another query using DateDiff, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone help?

My code is below.

```
    <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pokemon ORDER BY stats");

            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>Pokemon Name</th>
            <th>Type One</th>
            <th>Type Two</th>
            <th>Move One</th>
            <th>Move Two</th>
            <th>Move Three</th>
            <th>Move Four</th>
            <th>Stats</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date Added</th>
            <th>Days on File</th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $query = "SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE, $row[dAdded])FROM pokemon AS days";
                $date =  mysqli_query($con, $query);


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['type1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['type2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['move1'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['move2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['move3'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['move4'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['stats'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dAdded'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $date . "days</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the datediff to the original query. You'll also need to use fetch_assoc rather than fetch_array so that you can reference the field names in $row.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, DATEDIFF(CURDATE, dAdded) as dDate FROM pokemon ORDER BY stats");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

}
```

Comment: This is a nice addition and less overhead :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is within your `DATEDIFF()` function, more specifically with `$row[dAdded]`. Shouldn't this be `$row['dAdded']` with the quotes? And also I believe `CURDATE` needs the parenthesis like `CURDATE()`.

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), $row['dAdded'])
```